AuthJs в next js
я добавил firebase адаптор  используя
официальное руководство по authjs
Но при выполнение входа выдается такая ошибка
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
После того как убираю реплэйс то выдает другую ошибку
Server Error
Error: Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Может кто ни будь поможет решить эту проблему
